# grep/egrep the star operator not matching all occurrences

Tags: regex, linux, macos, bash, grep

Let's take the string `AaAa`. I want to match the `a`s:

```
$ echo AaAa | grep -o a
a
a
```

So it is printing every match and not just the first one. When I add a star after the `a` I get the following

```
$ echo AaAa | grep -o 'a*'
$
```

Why did grep not output every match this time? I know it matched because if we remove the `-o` option it prints the whole line:

```
$ echo AaAa | grep 'a*'
AaAa
```

To see how many matches it should have matched I used `sed`:

```
$ echo AaAa | sed 's/a*/x/g'
xAxAx
```

The strings that were substituted for `x` should have been what `grep -o` printed. So the matches are as follows:

1. The null string in the beginning for matching `a` zero times
2. The first `a`
3. The second `a`

Why didn't it print the following?

```
$ echo AaAa | grep -o 'a*'

a
a
$
```

***EDIT***

The above was done with GNU grep 2.5.1
The following was done with GNU grep 2.6.3

```
$ echo AaAa | grep -o 'a*'
a
a
$
```

Notice that it still didn't print the first null string on its own line. It seems the bug was partially fixed in this newer release. Shouldn't there be a null string matched as well, like the `sed` example above?

Comment: try echo AaAa | grep a.*

Comment: You are using an unquoted `*`, which could be matching a file/folder.

Comment: Interesting. I can reproduce this in GNU grep 2.5.1 (OSX 10.7.5) with single-quoted strings, but not in GNU grep 2.10 (Ubuntu 12.04). The regex `a+` returns both matches on both systems.

Comment: @whereswalden I am having the same issue. The problem occurs with GNU grep 2.5.1 (OSX 10.7.5) but not with GNU grep 2.6.3 (CentOS 6). I guess this was a bug in the older versions of grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with this:

```
$ echo AaAa | grep -o 'a*'
$
```

You mentioned this was run on version `2.5.1`. This appears to be a bug in `grep` that seems to have been fixed in `2.5.3`.

Here's a quote from [GNU grep development](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/devel.html):

```
2.5.3
=====
Fix the combinations:
 * -i -o
 * --colour -i
 * -o -b
 * -o and zero-width matches
Go through the bug list im my mailbox and fix fixable.
Fix bugs reported with 2.5.2.
```

`-o` and zero-width matches is the bug we seem to be dealing with here. Zero width assertions don't consume characters in the string to the match, but they are still assertions so they do have to match. In this case, our zero width assertion is matching the character `a` zero times.

On to the next part:

```
$ echo AaAa | grep -o 'a*'
a
a
$
```

I think the reason you don't get a blank line here is just that the `-o` flag just doesn't print anything for zero width assertions.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the duplicates using `awk`:

```
$ echo AaAa | grep -o a|awk '!x[$0]++'
a
```